# How to format a cell to turn a color based on the text value of a cell that corresponds to a list of text values

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In cells A1:A500 I have names like "Fred Flintstone" for example. In cells B1:B500, I have a drop down box that indicates "PASS" or "FAIL". In cells AA1:AA500 I have created a formula that will pull only the names from A1:A500 that have "FAIL" in their respective B1:B500 column.

What conditional formula could I use so that in cells C1:C500, they will turn yellow if there is a name on the list of names that is contained in AA1:AA500?

So if A1 equals "Fred Flintstone" and he is a "FAIL" in B1, his name gets put into AA1.  I then need Cell C1 to turn yellow based on the fact that his name appeared on the AA list.

Comment: So can we ignore column **A** and column **AA** and only examine column **B** ?

Comment: No, because I already have a conditional format that turns it one color when the value for B1 is "FAIL".  I need it yellow when their name shows up on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on cell **C1** and apply conditional formatting with the "formula is" option:

```
=COUNTIF(AA:AA,A1)=1
```

and pick yellow as the background color.

Then copy **C1** and PasteSpecialFormats to the rest of column **C**

Comment: I had to tweak that formula to suit my needs, but it pointed me in the right direction.  Thank you.  I still need the cell to turn one more color, any ideas on how to accomplish this? For example.

Comment: I had to tweak that formula to suit my needs, but it pointed me in the right direction, thank you.  I still need the cell to turn one more color, any ideas on how to accomplish this? This is what I have so far:  A1="Fred Flintstone" and B1="FAIL",then C1 turns yellow. If text is entered into D1, it turns white unless their name appears on list AA1:AA500, then it stays yellow.  Now if their name appears on AA1:AA500 and AB1:AB500="PASS" and D1 has text in it, I need D1 to turn back to white.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MATCH` to see if the name appears in column AA. I suggest something like this:

1. Select the cells to be highlighted (make sure that you start with cell C1 to make it the active cell).

   [image]
2. Insert the `MATCH` formula, wrapped in `ISNUMBER` to get a boolean value. `MATCH` returns a number (the row number of a match) or an error (if there are no matches):

   [image]

   ```
   =isnumber(match(A1,AA$1:AA$500,0))
   ```

   And make sure you have the appropriate format picked.
3. Click OK and you should be done:

   [image]